# "I don't see them for dirt"

Tags: phrase-usage

A line from *[Stanley & Iris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_%26_Iris)*

> There are lots of pretty women in this town, but **I don't see them for dirt**. I keep thinking about the one who sleeps with her arms above her head and has a little mole, never mind where.

"I don't see them for dirt" sounds a little strange--just a little. The meaning is clear, but I am not sure about this construction. I guess it means "I don't think too much of them" or "I don't see much in them". But "not see something for dirt" doesn't appear to be idiomatic. Considering that to "see A for B" means to realize A is B, I am not sure "I don't see them for dirt" makes sense structurally. This question is about the idiomatic use and syntactic structure of "not see someone for something". Any other attestations of similar usages?

More background: Robert De Niro's character Stanley is poorly educated and illiterate. Iris, played by Jane Fonda, helps him learn to read and write. Stanley goes away to take a job in another city and writes a letter to Iris, from which the line in question is excerpted. Stanley is saying that although he sees a lot of pretty women in his new environment, only Iris is on his mind.

Comment: I thought "I don't see them for dirt" means that there are too many "not pretty women" and it is hard to spot the pretty ones through them.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Stanley is illiterate and poorly educated. The phrase could be something that De Niro invented as something his character might say.

Comment: @AIQ - The phrase means that, even though there “are lots of pretty women in this town”, it does not matter to the speaker. The pretty women might as well be “dirt”. Because, he does not see them as worth anything more than that compared to “the one who sleeps with her arms above her head and has a little mole, never mind where”. “The one” he loves is the only woman he can “see” with himself. She is above all of the rest.

Comment: A similar structure occurs in "to see someone FOR what they are", or "see something FOR what it is", meaning to identify something correctly. It usually has a negative sense, meaning to see past illusion. In that use, "for" could be replaced by "as", so that might be part of the puzzle.

Comment: The AHD definition of "for", 6a: a. As being: take for granted; mistook me for the librarian. Then, adding a negation, Stanley doesn't see them "as being" even dirt.

Comment: Another option is that "dirt" is being substituted for "shit". "for shit" is used colloquially in various ways to mean something is worthless or is nothing. It's still a bit weird, but I could see Stanly trying to be more polite when talking to Iris. An example of that sort of usage is "I can't dance for shit, even after taking lessons".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty "To see someone for what they are" was actually where I started with this question. "To see someone (A) for what they are (B)" is to **realize** someone is really just that. "_I finally saw her for the cheater that she was_" means "I finally realized she was just a cheater." But the line at issue appears totally different with the negative marker _not_. "I don't consider them dirt." is quite the opposite of its real meaning. As ColleenV says this line is from a largely illiterate character and probably intentionally nonidiomatic. "not even dirt" is perhaps the closest reading.